# Задача не проходит часть тестов. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Tags: java, поиск

Решаю задачу из Яндекс.Контеста. Проходит 15 тестов, на 16 пишет, что неверный ответ. Наверняка упускаю какое-то граничное условие, но уже перепробовал всё, что пришло в голову: в случае, когда есть 2 равных по длине пути от города А до города Б, подсчитываются дороги кратчайшего из них (пример такого варианта оставлю внизу). Несуществующие выдают -1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть загвоздка?

**G. Интересное путешествие**

**Ограничение времени**     1 секунда

**Ограничение памяти**  64Mb

**Ввод**    стандартный ввод или input.txt

**Вывод**   стандартный вывод или output.txt

Не секрет, что некоторые программисты очень любят путешествовать. Хорошо всем известный программист Петя тоже очень любит путешествовать, посещать музеи и осматривать достопримечательности других городов.

Для перемещений между из города в город он предпочитает использовать машину. При этом он заправляется только на станциях в городах, но не на станциях по пути. Поэтому он очень аккуратно выбирает маршруты, чтобы машина не заглохла в дороге. А ещё Петя очень важный член команды, поэтому он не может себе позволить путешествовать слишком долго. Он решил написать программу, которая поможет ему с выбором очередного путешествия. Но так как сейчас у него слишком много других задач, он попросил вас помочь ему.

Расстояние между двумя городами считается как сумма модулей разности по каждой из координат. Дороги есть между всеми парами городов.

**Формат ввода**

В первой строке входных данных записано количество городов n (2≤n≤1000). В следующих n строках даны два целых числа: координаты каждого города, не превосходящие по модулю миллиарда. Все города пронумерованы числами от 1 до n в порядке записи во входных данных.

В следующей строке записано целое положительное число k, не превосходящее двух миллиардов, — максимальное расстояние между городами, которое Петя может преодолеть без дозаправки машины.

В последней строке записаны два различных числа — номер города, откуда едет Петя, и номер города, куда он едет.

**Формат вывода**

Если существуют пути, удовлетворяющие описанным выше условиям, то выведите минимальное количество дорог, которое нужно проехать, чтобы попасть из начальной точки маршрута в конечную. Если пути не существует, выведите -1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
static final String input = "input.txt";
static final String output = "output.txt";
static BufferedReader br;
static BufferedWriter bw;

static int maxDistance;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));

    int citiesN = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int[] x = new int[citiesN];
    int[] y = new int[citiesN];

    for (int i = 0; i < citiesN; i++) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        x[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        y[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

    }

    maxDistance = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    int startCity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) - 1;
    int endCity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1;


    swap(x, y, 0, startCity);
    swap(x, y, x.length - 1, endCity);

    int[][] matrix = new int[citiesN][citiesN];
    for (int i = 0; i < citiesN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < citiesN; j++) {

            int distance = Math.abs(x[j] - x[i]) + Math.abs(y[j] - y[i]);
            if (distance <= maxDistance) {
                matrix[i][j] = distance;
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int minWays = dijkstra(matrix);
    bw.write(String.valueOf(minWays));
    br.close();
    bw.close();
}

private static void swap(int[] x, int[] y, int source, int startCity) {
    int temp = x[source];
    x[source] = x[startCity];
    x[startCity] = temp;

    temp = y[source];
    y[source] = y[startCity];
    y[startCity] = temp;
}

public static int dijkstra(int[][] adjacencyMatrix) {
    int v = adjacencyMatrix.length;

    boolean[] visited = new boolean[v];
    int[] distance = new int[v];

    distance[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < v; i++) {
        distance[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    int count = 1;
    int resultCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < v - 1; i++) {
        // Find Vertex with Min distance
        int minVertex = findMinVertex(distance, visited);
        visited[minVertex] = true;
        // Explore neighbours
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            if (adjacencyMatrix[minVertex][j] != 0 && !visited[j] && distance[minVertex] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                int newDist = distance[minVertex] + adjacencyMatrix[minVertex][j];
                if (newDist < distance[j]) {
                    distance[j] = newDist;
                    if (j == v - 1) {
                        resultCount = count;
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        count++;

    }
    if (resultCount == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else return resultCount;
}

private static int findMinVertex(int[] distance, boolean[] visited) {
    int minVertex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
        if (!visited[i] && (minVertex == -1 || distance[i] < distance[minVertex])) {
            if (minVertex == -1)
                minVertex = i;
            else
                if (distance.length-1-minVertex<distance.length-1-i)
                    minVertex = i;

        }
    }
    return minVertex;
}
```

}

Пример с 2 одинаковыми путями:

```
5
0 0
0 2
3 3
3 2
3 1
5
1 3
```

Comment: Найден ли ответ или решение? Я наткнулся на такую же задачу, решил ее через BFS. Также на 15м тесте вылетает неправильный ответ. Тест не виден.

Comment: Кто-нибудь решил? Я сделал через BFS, вылетает на 21-м тесте с out of time.

Comment: Здесь какое-то сложное решение. Какие-то матрицы... Мне хватило массива для учета посещенных вершин и очереди для последовательного обхода. Ну то есть BFS, да

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно найти количество дорог, то зачем здесь distance?

```
  if (distance <= maxDistance) {
            matrix[i][j] = distance;
```

Чтобы в Дейкстре учитывались перегоны, а не их протяжённость, достаточно

```
  matrix[i][j] = 1;
```

Кроме того, Дейкстра избыточен, хватит BFS (поиска в ширину)

Comment: Я поначалу решил, что нужно учитывать и расстояние до конечного города: может оказаться так, что одна трасса в 500 км, а при этом пятью объездными дорожками можно доехать за 100 км. С "matrix[i][j] = 1" ситуация аналогичная - падает на том же тесте(

Comment: Ещё у вас в матрице получается единица, когда i=j, т.е. петля в графе. В дальнейшей обработке это учитывается?

Answer (score 1):

У меня таже проблема была с вылетом за пределы значений int при расчёте расстояний.

Надо испоьзовать long, когда расстояния считаешь.

Comment: Подтверждаю. У меня так было, пока этот ответ не увидел)) Причем, в какой-то момент решения я немного задумывался над этим, но почему-то ошибся и посчитал, что int-а хватит.